# Interacting with Lists in SPFx?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

I would like to start building SFPx web parts which interact with lists in my site, but I am having a hard time figuring out List interactions. Where can I go other than the tutorials from Microsoft ([Here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/connect-to-sharepoint); These seem to go from very basic to very complex without a middle step).

I've tried to figure out sfpxHelper and spServices, but neither had documentation I was able to follow to get these setup properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do CRUD operations with SharePoint lists and libraries, you can take a look at the GitHub sample by Waldek Mastykarz.

The sample does CRUD operations on SharePoint lists using multiple frameworks like React, Angular, PnP js and simple NoScript sample as well.

It will give you a basic idea to create , update and delete items in the SharePoint list. The NoScript sample uses spHttpClient to do these operations.

Github reference link - [SharePoint CRUD](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/sharepoint-crud)

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the kind of thing I've been looking for (now that I figured out how to get it to `gulp serve` properly )!